# How to make JavaFX Stage always on bottom?

Tags: javafx

There is a setAlwaysOnTop() method, but I need make a 'always-on-bottom' windows or a window pinned to the desktop to, I want to create a application work like Windows 7 Gadgets.

Comment: Windows Gadgets is not 'alwaysOnBottom'. Please describe the feautre in a more detailed way. I mean - how it is suppose to behave.

Comment: Well, some thing like Rainmeter,https://www.rainmeter.net/

Comment: I've installed Rainmeter and it is not always on the bottom. So let's rule out that from conversation. In my opinion you need undecorated Stage with transparent (semi transparent) background. And that is all. Try to implement it and you'll see you'll get Rainmeter look and feel features. In case of issues I can help with some advice.

Comment: ok, thanks. Some Rainmeter's widget can do this (always in the bottom) but I can't show you, I will try to find a method to implement this.

Comment: Please describe how should always on the bottom should behave and please provide widget which implements the feature. Maybe then I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Window management in general is something that the operating system has to take care of. The JVM (and hence JavaFX, too) only uses OS features. So, in Java/JavaFX, we can only use those features that the JVM + Java + JavaFX API uses. AFAIK, there is no method like "always on bottom" there (and also not in some other development environments that let you build native applications).

If you need to send windows to the background or even need to monitor window depth, then you are looking for OS features. You would have to use the Windows Platform SDK. You would need to use the Java Native Interface e.g., in order to call Windows functions from Java.